# YOLOv8 android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, object-detection, real-time, yolov8

So i got this code from combining some codes. I expect this code to run well with android/mobile camera. So... the camera works but the bounding-box code is the problem. Because when i run the code, the app keeps stopping/shutting down. Can anyone tell how to fix this code?

```
                val outputs = model.process(inputFeature0)
                val outputFeature0 = outputs.outputFeature0AsTensorBuffer.floatArray


                var mutable = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
                val canvas = Canvas(mutable)

              var h = bitmap.height
              var w = bitmap.width
                paint.textSize = h/15f
                paint.strokeWidth = h/85f

// the error part :
              var x = 0
                outputFeature0.forEachIndexed { index, fl ->
                    x = index
                    x *= 4
                    if(fl > 0.5){
                        paint.setColor(colors.get(index))
                        paint.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
                        canvas.drawRect(RectF(outputFeature0.get(x+1)*w, outputFeature0.get(x)*h, outputFeature0.get(x+3)*w, outputFeature0.get(x+2)*h), paint)
                        paint.style = Paint.Style.FILL
                        canvas.drawText(labels.get(outputFeature0.get(index).toInt())+" "+fl.toString(), outputFeature0.get(x+1)*w, outputFeature0.get(x)*h, paint)
                    }
                }

                imageView.setImageBitmap(mutable)
```